# Key release listener in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listener, keyup

So far I have only found `<p:hotkey/>` in Primefaces which executes when the specified key is typed, but I would like to find also a listener 'key-is-released' (key is up) to revert a mode

Comment: How would you define a "key is released"-event in your own words? And to which input component does this apply?

Comment: In this API 'KeyUp' will be equivalent https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#keyUp-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-int-

Comment: AFAIK, `p:inputText` already supports a `keyup`-event: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml

Comment: This should be free, not in any component - when `CTRL` is pressed then some value is set to true, and when released set back to false. In that case `p:hotkey` seems to be okay but there's no option for `release-key` listener, only for `press-key`

Comment: You mean globally for a `p:form` regardless of a specific component?

Comment: Yes, this can be for `h:form` too :)